# How to add wait / Delay until web page is fully loaded in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: webautomation, rpa, automationanywhere

I want to know 'How to add wait or Delay until webpage is fully loaded,' in automations anywhere,
I used

> wait for screen change

But it hold the process until some time specified by the developer , but I want to add delay until the web page fully loaded, 
Is there anyone can help me?
sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, a website is "loaded" or "ready" before the actual content is loaded. Some websites even have dummy content which is replaced once the actual content is retrieved from 'somewhere'. Hence waiting for the screen to change is not a good idea.

My approach is to pick an element which you know is loaded **after** the element you want to interact with. For instance the navigation bar on this website is loaded before the comments are. You can either figure out which element to use by looking at the `source` of the website by right-clicking anywhere and selecting `view source` or by simply refreshing the page a couple of times and eye-balling it. The former requires some HTML knowledge, but is a better approach in my opinion.

Once you've identified your element, use `Object Cloning` on said element and use the built-in `wait` as a delay (usually set to 15 sec, depending on the website/connection). The `Action` should be some random `get property` (store whatever you retrieve in some dummy variable as we're not going to use it anyway).

`Object Cloning`'s wait function polls every so many milliseconds and once the element is found it will almost instantaneously go to the next line in the code. This is where you interact with your target element.

This way you **know** your target element is loaded and the code is very optimized and robust.

On a final note: It's usually a good idea to surround this with some exception handling as automating websites is prone to errors.

Comment: thanks , Roel i'll check and , let you know the progress and mark as answer.

Comment: Thanks Roel, for the answer. great answer.

Answer (score -2):

A very simple solution is to run your automation while watching and determine the amount of time it takes for the webpage to load. You can add a Delay rather than a wait if you know the page is generally loaded within 30 seconds or so.

Comment: web page loading is depend on various things like , bandwith , content of the page etc. so i dont think time is a good point for add waiting,

Comment: If you've ever used delays in the way I described you'd see that it works almost all the time. Why build something complicated that may break? If you've studied a webpage long enough and understand how it works this is the better way. Of course you can use wait for screen change commands but only if you need a popup in order to complete the next line, like an object cloning statement, to work. If not - add a delay.